# Where to get DoubleClick ads unitID

Tags: java, android

I am building my app and I want to implement ads to my app. I made everything work with test ID, that is: '/6499/example/interstitial', but I can't find where to find custom ID that will use real ads attached to my account.

I want to show ads in my app, for whose I will get paid for people viewing them. I dont know where to sign in or where I will get the custom ID for my ads.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to use a DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) as Provider for ads or use AdMob ads?

Comment: DoubleClick by Google refers to the DoubleClick Digital Marketing platform which is a separate division within Google. This is Google’s most advanced advertising tools set, which includes five interconnected platform components.

Comment: I want to show ads in my app, for whose I will get paid for people viewing them. I dont know where to sign in or where I will get the ID for my ads.

Comment: pleas edit/rewrite question and add this from comment to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several choices - which ad network to use (or use a multiple)
best one is a AdMob

1. read about https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
2. sign up for AdMob account https://www.google.pl/admob/

> error Our records indicate that you aren't eligible to participate in
>   AdMob at this time. Please review our Terms and Conditions. Learn more
>   – Jacky

more on sign up errors:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356424?hl=en&ref_topic=7384587

you can try this solution from video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IGyTk_wmiM

or search any other video tutorial (on YouTube) which will guide you through signup proces for AdMob account.

** *DoubleClick by Google refers to the DoubleClick Digital Marketing platform which is a separate division within Google. This is Google’s most advanced advertising tools set, which includes five interconnected platform components.*

*** *AdMob is essentially a mobile ad network also owned by Google. They allow app developers to monetize their apps and also promote them.*

Comment: error

Our records indicate that you aren't eligible to participate in AdMob at this time. Please review our Terms and Conditions. Learn more

Comment: what country are u in ? and what of google account did you use to signup ?

Comment: @jacky - glad to hear - please accept answer and up vote :) thanks